# C++. Dealing with classes and a unfamiliar part of a class

Tags: c++

Ive seen in a class the the follwing code...I was wondering what does the example part mean wiht the < and  > part mean.?? Ive used the search engine but cannot find anything ting on this topic.

```
class MyClass : public Baseclass<example>
{

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `Baseclass` is a class template. `example` is probably a type. `Baseclass<example>` is a class. `MyClass` is a class derived from `Baseclass<example>`.

Comment: C++, and programming in general, uses syntax that is often very hard to look up online if you don't know the correct terminology. As antiquated as this may seem, the best way to pick up this terminology is with [a good set of reference materials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).